# How to type hint a parameter, so the value must be an attribute of a class?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm using the following class (it's from Airflow code, so I can't modify it):

```py
class TriggerRule:
    """Class with task's trigger rules."""

    ALL_SUCCESS = 'all_success'
    ALL_FAILED = 'all_failed'
    ALL_DONE = 'all_done'
    ONE_SUCCESS = 'one_success'
    ONE_FAILED = 'one_failed'
    NONE_FAILED = 'none_failed'
    NONE_FAILED_OR_SKIPPED = 'none_failed_or_skipped'
    NONE_SKIPPED = 'none_skipped'
    DUMMY = 'dummy'

    _ALL_TRIGGER_RULES: Set[str] = set()

    @classmethod
    def is_valid(cls, trigger_rule):
        """Validates a trigger rule."""
        return trigger_rule in cls.all_triggers()

    @classmethod
    def all_triggers(cls):
        """Returns all trigger rules."""
        if not cls._ALL_TRIGGER_RULES:
            cls._ALL_TRIGGER_RULES = {
                getattr(cls, attr)
                for attr in dir(cls)
                if not attr.startswith("_") and not callable(getattr(cls, attr))
            }
        return cls._ALL_TRIGGER_RULES
```

Let's say I have this function:

```py
def print_rule(rule):
    print(rule)
```

and I want to type hint the parameter `rule` so it must be one of the rules listed in the `TriggerRule` class.

```py
print_color(TriggerRule.ALL_FAILED)  # OK
print_color('one_success')  # I don't care if it complains or not
print_color('foo')  # I want it to complain
```

Is this possible? I don't want to type it as `str` because I don't want to allow any string.

I'm using Python 3.8, but if this is possible in a newer version, I'd like to know as well.

Comment: Make it an enum?

Comment: It's a great comment. I forgot to mention the detail that `class Color` is part of a library.

Comment: Does the Colors class only have those attributes or are there other?

Comment: I've added the actual class I wan't to type. Maybe the `Colors` one wasn't the best idea.

Comment: can't you check for membership? so if it is part of `TriggerRule`, you're golden. I don't really understand this: _"I want to type hint the parameter rule so it must be one of the rules listed"_

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of a question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738177/how-to-define-a-given-functions-input-must-be-a-variable-static-of-a-class). Unfortunately, also here there's no solution for this yet. In the end this would be only for `Mypy` checks. There won't be any "automatic" static type magic performed.